# Eclipse RCP: org.eclipse.ui.views.showView Parameters

Tags: view, parameters, command, eclipse-rcp

I want to show a specific view in my RCP application using a command. Using showView opens a dialog to select view. Is there any way to do without selection dialog? I tried parameters but didn't help. Related part of plugin.xml is below.
                
           
           
           
            
com.dbtek.hyperbola.views.contactsView is my view ID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a command parameter with the id of the view to show. E.g.

```xml
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution
         locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
      <menu
            id="window"
            label="Window">
         <command
               commandId="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView"
               label="Show Progress"
               style="push">
            <parameter
                  name="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.viewId"
                  value="org.eclipse.ui.views.ProgressView">
            </parameter>
         </command>
      </menu>
   </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I already did the same thing but the selection dialog keeps opening. My code:

Comment: '<command
                  commandId="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView"
                  icon="icons/sample.gif"
                  label="Add Contact"
                  style="push">
     <commandParameter
              id="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.viewId"
              name="%command.showView.viewIdParameter"
              value="com.dbtek.hyperbola.views.contactsView" />
     <commandParameter
           id="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.makeFast"
           name="%command.showView.makeFastParameter"
           optional="true">
     </commandParameter>
            </command>'

Comment: This is the declaration for the showView command??!? Your definition should not include `commandParameter` elements, only `parameter` elements.