# enabling ShowView menu for rcp application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I created a sample eclipse rcp application and create some Views.
I added a Window menu and under that added command `org.eclipse.ui.window.showViewMenu`
for showing the ShowView functionality of eclipse. But when I run my rcp application `Showview` is disabled.
How can I enable the ShowView menu for my rcp application? Even if it is enabled, will
I get option for Seeing only the views which I created associated with my eclipsed rcp application?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881581/eclipse-rcp-how-to-get-show-view-menu-instead-of-a-dialog and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490157/eclipse-rcp-org-eclipse-ui-views-showview-parameters

Comment: @ greg-449 . Thanks for the information. It works fine. But I am facing a small issue. In my application there are some menus are created via extension point. So when I add the menu for Window in ApplicationActionBarAdvisor , order is getting changed. I mean menus are added through extension point, comes second which I dont want. I know becuase ApplicationActionBarAdvisor executer first. So Is there any way to change the  order?

Comment: You can add placeholder separators in the advisor with an id - `new Separator("id")`. The extension point menu items can refer to this to set the position.